# why is easy_install using python 2.6 for zeromq binding installation?

Tags: python, zeromq

```
sudo easy_install pyzmq
Searching for pyzmq
Best match: pyzmq 13.0.2
Processing pyzmq-13.0.2-py2.6-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
pyzmq 13.0.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyzmq-13.0.2-py2.6-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for pyzmq
Finished processing dependencies for pyzmq
```

now I have to run my python programs with zeromq like this

```
python2.6 program.py
```

My default python is python 2.7. 
How to install the pyzmq module with python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

probably because the `easy_install` on your path is for Python 2.6.

Check the output of

```
which easy_install
head -n 1 $(which easy_install)
```

And you will probably have your answer.  You may need to install or reinstall setuptools / distribute for Python 2.7, or just make sure the Python 2.7 easy_install is ahead of the 2.6 one on your PATH.  You can try

```
which -a easy_install
```

to see where multiple easy_installs are on your PATH.

Comment: Also to further clarify - pyzmq is irrelevant here, this would affect any and all packages you try to easy_install.